# jQuery autocomplete results to a custom drop down list (at select option tags )

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, drop-down-menu

I want to show my autocomplete results in select option tags instead of the default which is ul li with some jquery classes added (which I don't really want).

I'm using a code from a relative post here in stack overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/yRwH7/ as an example.

It loads correctly the first time actually but after that, nothing.
Any suggestions? Is there any other way to do it?
the code is here http://jsfiddle.net/yRwH7/1/

Javascript

```
 $("input#selectedInput").bind("autocompleteselect", function (event, ui) {
      alert("Sel item " + JSON.stringify(ui.item.json));
 }).autocomplete({
 appendTo: "#list",
 source: function (request, response) {

     $.ajax({
         url: "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson&entity=musicTrack",
         dataType: "jsonp",
         data: {
             featureClass: "P",
             style: "full",
             maxRows: 12,
             name_startsWith: request.term
         },

         success: function (data) {
             response($.map(data.results, function (item) {
                 itunesJson = item;
                 return {
                     label: "<option>" + item.trackName + "</option>",
                 }
             }));
             var elm = $("#list");
             elm.html(elm.text());
         },
     });
 }
 })​
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="selectedInput"/>
<select id="list"></select>
```

Comment: ok i could not solve it but heres a hint if you use firebug you can see the select actually has data but without <option> tags

Comment: I know and this is kind of strange. Anyway, thanks for your try! :)

Answer (score 0):

i tried the demo and modified it

am using firefox

here is the link [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/NdMB9/2/)

looks it needed a space after div may be browser compatability issue